# How to tell the UITableView to bounce into place programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

My goal is pretty straightforward:

The user should be able to move cells in the UITableView up and down by using the provided buttons. I want the new selected cell to appear exactly where the old selected cell was with the exception of the scrolling being at the the beginning of end of the tableview.

I tried using

```
[table selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:false scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

But the problem is that the row is always moved to the same position near the center of the screen which I don't want.

I want to center the

```
table.contentOffset.y
```

exactly where I am programmatically placing it. However, when I set this with

```
[table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, newVerticalContentOffset)];
```

so I did exactly that. Now I have the problem of the scrolling going way outside the the table and even the normal bounce range. The only way to get it to 'bounce' back is if the user scroll touches the list.

I also tried programmatically setting the offset to the 'min' and 'max' of it happened to go out of those bounds. However, I realized that this was complicated because I have to add the height of the navigation bar and the status bar to get the top coordinates and get the content size to determine the bottom. I think it would be easier if there was simply a way to programmatically 'bounce' or 'release' the tableview back into place. I tried calling the table's delegate with flags like

```
scrollViewDidScroll
```

This crashes my application. I realized that even if I did perform one of these last two solutions, that the action would still not represent my goal. If I move a cell down from the top, the view scrolls with it. I do not want that to happen because it is very close to the top. In this case, I wouldn't mind it making its way to the middle before scrolling the view.

The best idea I have so far is somehow attempting to center scroll the cell and if it is able to be centered (meaning it is not near the top or bottom), not to actually center it.

I thought about performing a centering then checking if the y coordinate changed by exactly 1 cell and leaving it if it did, otherwise using the old position. However, I imagine that the user may be somewhere near the middle of the list and happens to be exactly 1 cell away from the middle. When he moves the cell, it will move 'unexpectedly' which is not what I want.